# MySQL UUID_SHORT() gives error Out of range value for column

Tags: mysql, uuid, bigint

I'm using MySQL 5.6.17 on Amazon Web Services RDS and when calling SELECT UUID_SHORT() I'm getting a number bigger than **9223372036854775807**.  For example the number I get is

> 12057145185130250250

The problem is in my table I have a column as BIGINT(20) unsigned, but when storing a number **12057145185130250250** I get the error MySQL 22003

> 'MySQL 22003 Out of range value for column '' at row 1'

If I run `SELECT UUID_SHORT()` on our test server which is MySQL 5.6.11 (running on Windows 2008 64x) the result is as follows;

> 23526798209843216

I changed the column I'm trying to save my number to, as BIGINT(20) unsigned, but still get this error.

Any ideas why ?

**UPDATE**

Further to my initial post, I found that if I manually insert the value '12057145185130250250' using Workbench editor into the BIGINT(20) column, it saves fine.

However, if I save the value using a stored procedure like below this is when I get the problem;

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`testaccount`@`%` PROCEDURE `CreateCustomer`(iUserId
INTEGER, sPassword VARCHAR(75)) 

BEGIN

    DECLARE iSalt BIGINT;

    SELECT UUID_SHORT() INTO iSalt;

    INSERT INTO UserCustomer
    (
       UserId,
       Password,
       Salt
    )
    VALUES
    (
       iUserId,
       SHA2(CONCAT(iSalt,sPassword), 256),
       iSalt 
    );

END
```

Comment: unsigned bigint should be the right type and the range should be sufficient. The [manual for UUID_SHORT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) said: _Returns a “short” universal identifier as a 64-bit unsigned integer_

Comment: I have set unsigned BIGINT(20), but it isn't allowing me to store the number.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, see it in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/640478/6). Please attend to the differing results of both queries too. The second one with converting to string shows clearly that the value is correctly stored.

Comment: I've updated my question with some new information.

Comment: As I said, you have to declare your variable as `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, not as `BIGINT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BIGINT` and `BIGINT UNSIGNED` are not the same.  All the integer data types are signed unless explicitly unsigned.

But also, `UUID_SHORT()` is designed to produce unique but not random, not unpredictable, and always-incrementing values, which seems like a particularly bad choice for a salt, no?

...Especially since the `RANDOM_BYTES()` function was introduced in 5.6.17.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_random-bytes